# Visual Studio 2010 C++ & OpenGL project cannot detect .lib files

Tags: opengl, c++, visual-studio

So I'm trying to start a C++, OpenGL project on Visual Studio 2010, and I have put glut.h and glut32.dll in the project directory, along with the glut.dll and glut32.lib files in a folder named "glut" in the project directory.

I have also gone to "Porject Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies" and I have typed in "glut32.lib" at the end, and made sure I am not missing a semicolon.

when I try doing

```
#include "glut.h"
```

in the Main.cpp file, it complains

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.libkernel32.lib'
```

Am I missing any files? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'glut32.libkernel32.lib'

It looks like you're missing a separator character in your dependency options, glut32.lib and kernel32.lib are separate libraries. If you open the additional dependencies window, every entry should be on a new line.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that...thank you, I was sure I had semicolons everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Set the glut32.lib and kernel32.lib paths at Project Properties->configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.
If you don't have these lib files in local system/machine, you can download it from web.